# How to extract certain string from a text?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a certain feature "Location" from which I want to extract country.

The feature looks like:

```
data['Location'].head()

0    stockton, california, usa
1    edmonton, alberta, canada
2     timmins, ontario, canada
3      ottawa, ontario, canada
4                n/a, n/a, n/a
Name: Location, dtype: object
```

I want:

```
data['Country'].head(3)

0   usa
1   canada
2   canada
```

I've tried:

```
data['Country'] = data.Location.str.extract('(+[a-zA-Z])', expand=False)
data[['Location', 'Country']].sample(10)
```

which returns:

> error: nothing to repeat at position 1

When I try to put the '[a-zA-Z]+' it gives me city.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `data['Location'].str.split(',').str[-1]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data['Country'] = data['Location'].apply(lambda row: str(row).split(',')[-1])
```

You may do this, df.apply applies a function across all rows, our lambda function extracts the country, and apply is only called on one column and saved into another

Comment: The axis attribute shouldn't be there. Without that it works fine.

Comment: My bad, you are right, made changes to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regex patterns:

```
df['Country'] = df['Location'].str.split('(,\s)(\w+)$', n = 1, expand = True)[2]
```

Output:

```
df['Country'].head(3)
Out[111]: 
0       usa
1    canada
2    canada
Name: country, dtype: object
```

Comment: I would do extract because you want to extract it :) 
df['Country'] = df['Location'].str.extract(',\s([^,]+?)$')